# PHP json из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такую структуру json из PHP.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Структура таблицы MySQL:

```
+----+--------+--------+------------+------------+
| Id | Worker | Object | Date       | TimeWorker |
+----+--------+--------+------------+------------+
| 1  | 1      | 1      | 17.06.2019 | 8          |
| 2  | 1      | 1      | 18.06.2019 | 8          |
| 3  | 1      | 1      | 19.06.2019 | 8          |
| 4  | 1      | 1      | 20.06.2019 | 8          |
| 5  | 1      | 1      | 21.06.2019 | 8          |
| 6  | 1      | 2      | 24.06.2019 | 8          |
| 7  | 2      | 2      | 24.06.2019 | 8          |
+----+--------+--------+------------+------------+
```

INFO1:FullTimeWorker - Сумма TimeWorker, группировка по Worker.

INFO2:TimeWorker - Сумма TimeWorker, группировка по Object.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4SRqAS7J8U  вместо 1000 слов

Comment: А разве так получится сделать средствами MySQL:

array(array("A"=>"a", "B"=>array("A"=>"a","B"=>"b","C"=>"c")),array("A"=>"a", "B"=>array("A"=>"a","B"=>"b","C"=>"c")))

Comment: там обычный вывод - подключение к мискл выборка и как положено - посмотрите видео

Comment: Я посмотрел, как получить массив из MySQL и кодировать в json, я знаю.
А вот как сделать сложный json, из одной таблицы, не могу сообразить.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78FAtAcLvqY  динамичный json - поглянь это

Comment: =)Это тоже понятно всё.
Сейчас я пытаюсь сделать вот таким образом:
$res1 = $db->query("SELECT ---");
$result = array();
$result1 = array();
$result2 = array();
$tw_ = array();
//$user_info = array();      // создаем массив с данными
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($res1)) {
   $result1 = array (
      'Worker' => $row1['Worker'],
      'FullTimeWorker' => $row1['FullTimeWorker']
   );

Comment: $res2 = $db->query("SELECT ---");
   while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($res2)) {
      array_push($tw_, array(
         "WorkerName"=>$row2['WorkerName'],
         "ObjectName"=>$row2['ObjectName'],
         "TimeWorker"=>$row2['TimeWorker']
      ));
   }
   $result2 = array_push($result1, $tw_);
   $result = array_push($result, $result2);
}
print_r(json_encode($result));
Но что то не выходит в $result нужная структура.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем, разобрался как такой массив получить.

```
$tw_[] = array(
 "ObjectName"=>$row2['ObjectName'],
 "TimeWorker"=>$row2['TimeWorker']
);
```

И потом

```
$result1[] = array ("Worker"=>array (
 'Worker' => $row1['Worker'],
 'FullTimeWorker' => $row1['FullTimeWorker']
 ),"WorkerTime"=>array($tw_)
);
```